# Security concern with hosting a chrome extension on a public server

Tags: man-in-the-middle, chrome, web-hosting

We have chrome extension that is for internal use by our clients. It is force-installed via enterprise policy. So far, we have it published on the Chrome WebStore but we need to move off of it due to Manifest V3 restriction and host it on our own server. What would be some security concern we should be aware of and how can be guard against it? How can we prevent some type of man-in-the-middle attack where another malicious extension gets downloaded instead of ours.

Answer (score 1):

If your clients connect to your server by HTTPS, and your SSL certificate is signed by a well known certificate authority that is widely trusted, then a MITM attack by an attacker positioned between the client and your server is highly unlikely - even if the attacker has the ability to modify the packets as they traverse the network.  HTTPS is designed to mitigate this type of attack.  So, if your clients connect to your server by HTTPS, then it's reasonably safe to assume that an attacker on the network would be unable to modify your downloadable, as your client downloads your downloadable from your server.  [Of course, this assumes that your server's TLS implementation is secure - i.e. you are using an up to date version of TLS, you are protecting against downgrade attacks, etc].

However, if an attacker is able to gain access to your server, then the attacker may be able to replace your downloadable with a malicious file of his/her own.  HTTPS will not mitigate this type of attack.  The user's browser will show a secure connection to your server as it downloads the malicious file.

To mitigate this type of attack, your clients must verify the integrity of the downloadable after they download it, and before they install it.  One way to do this is for you to create a key pair, and distribute your public key to your clients, and keep your private key offline.  Every time you make a new release, use your private key to sign the downloadable file, and post the signature on your site, along with the downloadable.  Then, your clients can verify the signature on the downloadable (using your public key) to verify the integrity of the file.  If an attacker were to modify the file, this would break the signature.

Comment: Thank you for your response. Regarding customers verifying the signature, is that a manual process? In our setup, the install and update would happen automatically on browser startup. It would be initiated by chrome based on url specified in the registry as well as the update url specified in manifest of the extension. Customers won’t really have a chance for manual verification. By default there is a public and private key used to sign the extension when it is packed. Not sure if chrome would reject the extension replaced by a 3rd party

Comment: @blissfool It looks like there may already be a process in place for code signing and verification  for browser extensions.  See https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/34412/signing-a-browser-extension.